# python - bokeh: tooltip appearing partly out of figure

Tags: python, bokeh

I am plotting a chart with bokeh, having a tooltip appearing hover on glyph.

However the tooltip is mangled at the top and botom, being too large for the figure.

How can I leave some white space at the top and bottom in prevision of the tooltip appearing?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found this question unanswered while looking to do the same thing.  The solution I found was to use:

```
p.min_border_top = 75
p.min_border_bottom = 75
```

For 75 pixels

Actually I just used `p.min_border = 75` for all-round borders

The documentation for this is [here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html)